# Setting axes to semilog with Mayavi 3D plot

Tags: matplotlib, axes, mayavi, mplot3d, mayavi.mlab

I'm sucessfully generating a 3D plot with Mayavi, but can't find any way to rescale the axes to a semilog representation.

Is this possible?

I also tried taking a screenshot (as suggested by another answer I read before), which I placed after my mayavi code

```
arr = mayavi.mlab.screenshot()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
pylab.imshow(arr)

plt.semilogx()

plt.show()
```

However this just produces a segmentation fault.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're mixing `matplollib` with `mayavi`. If I'm correct, your plots involve `matplatlib` and not `mayavi`, so you might as well stick to the first.

Comment: To my knowledge, logarithmic scales can only be applied to colorbars in Mayavi.